# How to draw the "trail" in a maze solving application

Tags: python, graphics

Hello i have designed a maze and i want to draw a path between the cells as the 'person' moves from one cell to the next.
So each time i move the cell a line is drawn
Also i am using the graphics module

> The graphics module is an object oriented library

**Im importing**

```
from graphics import*
from maze import*
```

**my circle which is my cell**

```
center = Point(15, 15)
c = Circle(center, 12)
c.setFill('blue')
c.setOutline('yellow')
c.draw(win)

p1 = Point(c.getCenter().getX(), c.getCenter().getY())
```

**this is my loop**

```
 if mazez.blockedCount(cloc)> 2: 
            mazez.addDecoration(cloc, "grey")
            mazez[cloc].deadend = True
        c.move(-25, 0)
        p2 = Point(p1.getX(), p1.getY())
        line = graphics.Line(p1, p2)
        cloc.col = cloc.col - 1
```

> Now it says getX not defined every time i press a key is this because of p2???

**This is the most important bits in the module for this part**

```
def __init__(self, title="Graphics Window",
             width=200, height=200, autoflush=True):
    master = tk.Toplevel(_root)
    master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)
    tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, width=width, height=height)
    self.master.title(title)
    self.pack()
    master.resizable(0,0)
    self.foreground = "black"
    self.items = []
    self.mouseX = None
    self.mouseY = None
    self.bind("<Button-1>", self._onClick)
    self.height = height
    self.width = width
    self.autoflush = autoflush
    self._mouseCallback = None
    self.trans = None
    self.closed = False
    master.lift()
    if autoflush: _root.update()

def __checkOpen(self):
    if self.closed:
        raise GraphicsError("window is closed")
def setCoords(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    """Set coordinates of window to run from (x1,y1) in the
    lower-left corner to (x2,y2) in the upper-right corner."""
    self.trans = Transform(self.width, self.height, x1, y1, x2, y2)
def plot(self, x, y, color="black"):
    """Set pixel (x,y) to the given color"""
    self.__checkOpen()
    xs,ys = self.toScreen(x,y)
    self.create_line(xs,ys,xs+1,ys, fill=color)
    self.__autoflush()

def plotPixel(self, x, y, color="black"):
    """Set pixel raw (independent of window coordinates) pixel
    (x,y) to color"""
    self.__checkOpen()
    self.create_line(x,y,x+1,y, fill=color)
    self.__autoflush()
    def draw(self, graphwin):
    if self.canvas and not self.canvas.isClosed(): raise GraphicsError(OBJ_ALREADY_DRAWN)
    if graphwin.isClosed(): raise GraphicsError("Can't draw to closed window")
    self.canvas = graphwin
    self.id = self._draw(graphwin, self.config)
    if graphwin.autoflush:
        _root.update()
    def move(self, dx, dy):

    """move object dx units in x direction and dy units in y
    direction"""

    self._move(dx,dy)
    canvas = self.canvas
    if canvas and not canvas.isClosed():
        trans = canvas.trans
        if trans:
            x = dx/ trans.xscale 
            y = -dy / trans.yscale
        else:
            x = dx
            y = dy
        self.canvas.move(self.id, x, y)
        if canvas.autoflush:
            _root.update()
    class Point(GraphicsObject):
def __init__(self, x, y):
    GraphicsObject.__init__(self, ["outline", "fill"])
    self.setFill = self.setOutline
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def _draw(self, canvas, options):
    x,y = canvas.toScreen(self.x,self.y)
    return canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x+1,y+1,options)

def _move(self, dx, dy):
    self.x = self.x + dx
    self.y = self.y + dy

def clone(self):
    other = Point(self.x,self.y)
    other.config = self.config.copy()
    return other

def getX(self): return self.x
def getY(self): return self.y
def __init__(self, p1, p2, options=["outline","width","fill"]):
    GraphicsObject.__init__(self, options)
    self.p1 = p1.clone()
    self.p2 = p2.clone()

def _move(self, dx, dy):
    self.p1.x = self.p1.x + dx
    self.p1.y = self.p1.y + dy
    self.p2.x = self.p2.x + dx
    self.p2.y = self.p2.y  + dy

def getP1(self): return self.p1.clone()

def getP2(self): return self.p2.clone()

def getCenter(self):
    p1 = self.p1
    p2 = self.p2
    return Point((p1.x+p2.x)/2.0, (p1.y+p2.y)/2.0)
```

Comment: What graphic library/framework are you using?  Circle, Point, etc, are **not** part of Python proper, so you must be importing something... and you're not telling us *what*!-)

Comment: Which module?  Do you have a link to its documentation?

Comment: no i dont i was guna attach it but you cannot attach files on here

Comment: why what kind of modules are there ?

Comment: Where did you *get* the module?

Comment: You should ask your tutor how to use the library since it looks like he's written it himself. If not, maybe you can find out where it's obtained from so that we can have a look. We'd be able to help you much better then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this from an interactive Python shell:

```
>>> import graphics
>>> help(graphics.Circle)
```

That should tell you what attributes Circle does have.

Comment: ey fred that did help but i get a getx has no attribute but i type that in instead of help(graphics.Circle) but it cannot find it 
any help there?

Comment: dont worry i got it however still a problem

Comment: Also try `dir(graphics.Circle)`.

Comment: @snow-spur: In the line `p2 = Point(getX(), getY())`, I'm not sure what object `getX()` and `getY()` are supposed to be getting called on.  Those are probably methods of `Point`, right?  You can do a `help(graphics.Point)` to check.  I think your problem is now in that line, anyway.

Comment: yeh thanx fred i know its in that line ive found this in the module 
 def getX(self): return self.x
    def getY(self): return self.y

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `getX()` and `getY()` as free-standing **FUNCTIONS**:

```
p2 = Point(getX(), getY())
```

Note that you're calling them as bare names, *not* qualified names -- therefore, as functions, **not** as methods.

And yet the docs you quote say they're *methods* -- therefore, they must be called as part of qualified names ("after a dot"...!-) and before the dot must be an instance of `Point`.

Presumably, therefore, you need `p1.getX()` and `p1.getY()` instead of the bare names you're using.  `p1.getX` is a qualified name (i.e., one with a dot) and it means "method or attribute `getX` of object `p1`.

This is really super-elementary Python, and I recommend you first study the [official Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html) or other even simpler introductory documents before you try making or modifying applications in Python.

Comment: ey alex yeh thanx i changed that bit but now i have another problem. There is no error however it does not draw

Comment: @snow, if you don't consider this answer (which helped you fix an error and you're thanking me for) worth at least an upvote, then clearly you're just too hard to please and I won't spend more time on this (it's not as if I need the rep, but upvoting good answers is such a crucial part of Stack Overflow's etiquette that simply ignoring it is just plain insulting;-).

Comment: So where's any call to `.draw(win)` in your loop?  If you still need more help give us a URL to the `graphics` module or at least its docs, since of course we have no clue about how it works except from deductions from what little you tell us.

Comment: i have just update the module bit and copied the most important bits in

Comment: Since you've accepted an answer, this means that you think this question is solved (of course if there are other questions you can always open other questions for them).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `maze` solves the puzzle, so I am going to assume it works like a generator, `yield`ing the next move for the circle to make. Something to this effect:

```
while not this_maze.solved():
  next_position = this_maze.next()
  my_circle.move(next_position)
```

Then all you need to do is keep track of the current circle position and the previous circle position.

```
prev_position = this_maze.starting_point
while not this_maze.solved():
  next_position = this_maze.next()
  my_circle.clear()
  draw_trail(prev_position, next_position)
  my_circle.draw_at(next_position)
  prev_position = next_position
```

Obviously, changing this in something compatible with your framework is left up to you. `dir()`, `help()` and reading the libraries' source will all help you.